# python saving the excess of a float to int conversion

Tags: python

```
x=10.5
    if x==10.5:
        x=int(x)+1
        y= .5
```

ok i have x=10.5 i want to round up to 11 but say the .5 to use later is there any way to do this when i dont know what x will be all the time?

i have to real place to start or even if its possible i do know how to change it to an int but i want to store what ever it took off and store to y right now id have to write 100 of if statments to figure what do say and that just doent strike me as the best way to do it

Answer (score 7):

One fell swoop:

```
>>> divmod(10.5,1)
(10.0, 0.5)
```

The docs for `divmod` can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 10.5
x,chopped = int(x), x - int(x)
```

Comment: i fugured a way to do it that was simple i was over complicating it thanks for the help i just had to take a break at stareing at the code for it to come to me

Answer (score 1):

take the number modulus 1

```
>>> 10.5%1
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather poorly worded. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
x = 10.5

y = math.fmod(x, 1.0) # y = 0.5
x = math.ceil(x) # x = 11.0
```

Comment: i fugured a way to do it that was simple i was over complicating it thanks for the help i just had to take a break at stareing at the code for it to come to me